# VSCode: Integrated terminal selected lines not highlighted

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

[image]

In the integrated terminal of VSCode even though I have selected the line `print -c "print('Hello World')"` as shown in the above screenshot, it doesn't gets highlighted like **blue** **color** in my iTerm2 terminal as illustrated in the screenshot below
[image]

Any ideas what settings should I change to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `colorCustomization` in your `settings.json`:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "terminal.selectionBackground": "#f00"
  }
}
```

See [Customizing a color theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)

Comment: Thanks @Mark for your answer. It indeed work as expected